# How to use OpenGL ES extensions on Android

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, opengl-es-3.0

I am developing a OpenGL ES 3.0 application on Android, mainly in Java and I need to use floating point render textures.

```
GLES30.glGetString(GLES30.GL_EXTENSIONS)
```

returns a string containing GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float, and GL_EXT_color_buffer_float among others => my device supports floating point textures, obviously.

However, I am a bit lost right now how to use those extensions.
Calling

```
GLES30.glTexImage2D(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES30.GL_RGBA16F, 512, 512, 0, GLES30.GL_RGBA, GLES30.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
```

results in an glError 1282. Everything works when I use GL_RGBA instead of GL_RGBA16F. 
I wanted to try GL_RGBA16F_EXT, but that's not contained in GLES30. So, I tried to pass the value 0x881A which is how GL_RGBA16F_EXT is defined, I think. But, same error: glError 1282.

There is that function eglGetProcAddress which is sometimes needed to use OpenGL ES extensions, but since I don't need the address of a function, I suspect that won't help me either. I don't really know what to try next. How can i create floating point FBOs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` is not a valid value for the `type` argument of `glTexImage2D()` in combination with the `GL_RGBA16F` value for the `internalFormat` argument.

Based on table 3.2 in the spec, the only valid `type` values for `GL_RGBA16F` are `GL_HALF_FLOAT` and `GL_FLOAT`. This call should work:

```
GLES30.glTexImage2D(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES30.GL_RGBA16F, 512, 512, 0,
                    GLES30.GL_RGBA, GLES30.GL_HALF_FLOAT, null);
```

Unlike full OpenGL, OpenGL ES has a fairly limited set of valid `format`/`type`/`internalFormat` combinations for `glTexImage2D()`. It does not support automatic conversion of data types as part of this call beyond the value combinations listed in table 3.2 of the spec.

These `type` and `internalFormat` values still have to form a valid combination, even if no data is specified in the call. Mainly because... it's defined that way. In my personal opinion, this whole `glTexImage2D()` was never a good API design, and it partly also suffers from they way it evolved over time. The newer `glTexStorage2D()` is much cleaner.

For example, in this specific case, the `internalFormat` does indeed completely specify the storage format of the texture, because `GL_RGBA16F` is a sized format. So the `type` seems redundant. But the older unsized formats are still supported as well for backwards compatibility. Say if you specify `GL_RGB` for `internalFormat`, the texture will use a `GL_RGB8` internal format if you combine that with `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` for the `type`, but it will be a `GL_RGB565` if the `type` is `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5`.

Comment: Oh, you are right. Thanks! I thought, the type parameter is associated with the data parameter and hence, it would not matter what I specify for type because data=null. Obviously, I've misunderstood something there - which effect has the type parameter? Doesn't the internalFormat specify everything, the GPU needs to know?

Comment: Added some content to try and explain that. Even so it's kind of difficult to logically explain it because the way some of these APIs are defined is a total mess.